# SharePoint 2010-Putting a background image on 1 content page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-branding

I am new to SharePoint branding.  I want to put a background-image that covers the entire content part of one page.  When I put it in the Master page (e.g.,Additional Page Header), it bleeds onto all pages,lists, etc. in the site. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in sharepoint designer

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url('...');
}
</style>
</asp:Content>
```